# I don't understand why my generic type declaration doesn't match

Tags: java, generics

Here are the classes declarations:

```
public interface IPoint<N extends Number> {
...
}

public abstract class PointP<N extends Number> implements IPoint<N> {
...
}

public class Pointf extends PointP<Float> {
...
}

public interface ISegment<T extends Number, P extends IPoint<T>> {
...
}

public abstract class SegmentP<N extends Number, P extends IPoint<N>> implements ISegment<N, P> {
...
}

public class Segmentf extends SegmentP<Float, Pointf> {
...
}

public abstract class LinesPIterator<N extends Number, S extends ISegment<N, IPoint<N>>> implements Iterable<S>, Iterator<S> {
...
}

public class LinesfIterator extends LinesPIterator<Float, Segmentf> {
...
}
```

The compiler refuses the **Segmentf** type in the generic declaration of the **LinesfIterator** class with the error message:

```
Bound mismatch: The type Segmentf is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <S extends ISegment<N,IPoint<N>>> of the type LinesPIterator<N,S>
```

However for me everything seems correct. The declaration of the **LinesfIterator** class seems to me to have the same hierarchical schema as the **Segmentf** class which compiles without problem.

Is there a solution to this way of doing things?

Comment: Your inheritance hierarchy looks overly complex for no good reason.

Comment: Or, to put @Kayaman's point another way, I hope that this level of complexity is merited by the problem you are trying to solve. Such complex generics *may* be necessary, but it may be worth rethinking if you find them hard to use.

Comment: Let's say that I have to use objects composed of numeric types which must be able to be float or double according to the needs. I usually use the interface to transmit the object to other objects. The abstract class is used for the attributes and the implementations common to the subclasses and especially for the abstract methods to be obligatorily implemented by the subclasses. And finally the concrete class. I don't see how I could simplify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, your hierarchy seems to be unnecessarily complex and shall be simplified. For example, I see no meaning in `Pointf -> PointP -> IPoint` the hierarchy.

If you want to fix your issue, you have to allow a subtype `? extends IPoint<N>` in the `LinesPIterator` class, so:

```
public abstract class LinesPIterator<N extends Number, S extends ISegment<N, ? extends IPoint<N>>> 
    implements Iterable<S>, Iterator<S> 
{
    // ...
}
```

Moreover, there would be better to implement only `Iterable` as long as it provides an `Iterator` and you might end up with duplicated implementation.

```
public static class LinesfIterator extends LinesPIterator<Segmentf, Pointf, Float> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Segmentf> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Segmentf>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() { /* TO DO */ }

            @Override 
            public Segmentf next() { /* TO DO */ }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning too that making something implement both `Iterable` and `Iterator` is rather questionable. They are logically different things: the former is a supplier of the latter.

Comment: That's true. Implementing `Iterable` providing an anonymous implementation of `Iterator` would better. Otherwise the OP might end up with duplicated implementation.

Comment: What is the "OP"? 
I am trying to understand why an anonymous class would be better here but without success.
Is adding my code in response to the rest of this post allowed to discuss it?

Comment: "OP" in StackOverfloiw stans for the "original poster" - that's the author of the question which is you. About the anonymous class: If you implement both `Iterable` and `Iterator`, you have to provide a custom `Iterator` to implement `Iterable` and implement `next` and `hasNext` at the same time.

Comment: Sorry @Nikolas I don't understand why an anonymous class is better here. I added a post to show you my code.

Answer (score 0):

This remark on the use of an anonymous class rather than a direct use really caught my attention because intuitively, when I can avoid going through an anonymous class I do. On the one hand because it is an additional instantiation and on the other hand because it is more difficult to identify at debug (when they are several in the same class).
And I can't see the reasons why I should prefer the use of an anonymous class for this case.
Maybe with my classes as an example the explanation will be easier.

```
for(Segmentf segment : new LinesfIterator(cube.getPoints(), cube.getIndices())) {
    System.out.println(segment);
}

public abstract class LinesPIterator<N extends Number, S extends ISegment<N, ? extends IPoint<N>>> implements Iterable<S>, Iterator<S> {
    private N[][] points;
    private int[] indices;
    private int count;

    public LinesPIterator(N[][] points, int[] indices) {
        super();
        this.points = points;
        this.indices = indices;
    }

    protected abstract S instanciateIteration(final N[] pointDeb, final N[] pointFin);

    @Override
    public Iterator<S> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return count < (indices.length - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public S next() {
        return instanciateIteration(points[indices[count++]], points[indices[count++]]);
    }
}

public class LinesfIterator extends LinesPIterator<Float, Segmentf> {

    public LinesfIterator(Float[][] points, int[] indices) {
        super(points, indices);
    }

    @Override
    protected Segmentf instanciateIteration(Float[] point1, Float[] point2) {
        return new Segmentf(point1, point2);
    } 
}
```